# How to access globals from a different point in code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way of basically doing a late `eval`, using context from a different location in the code.  As an example, I have a class `Friend`, and it can be used like this:

```
>>> class A:
...     friend = Friend('B')
...
>>> class B:
...     friend = Friend('A')
...
>>> A.friend.getobject()
<class '__main__.B'>
```

However, `Friend` is defined elsewhere in the code, in a separate library, and would look something like this:

```
class Friend:

    def __init__(self, objname):
        self.objname = objname

    def getobject(self):
        return eval(self.objname, original_context)
```

The sqlalchemy ORM has a similar pattern for defining columns, but they implement it by tracking all owning classes (i.e. tables) in a session.  I could do something similar if I need to, but I'd like to know if there is another way to do this.  I've been looking at frames and the interpreter stack, and I think I can get to the relevant frame's locals using something like `inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals`, but I would have to do this in `Frame.__init__` which is called before the object is defined.

My questions is how to find `original_context`, but only at the time it is needed.  This comes down to two issues:
1. How to access the environment (or frame?) in which `Friend` was instantiated.
2. How to access it at the time `getobject` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the fully qualified classname, ie:

```
 class A:
     friend = Friend('themodule.B')
```

And then take that string, extract out the module and import the B class, and generate it like this.

However, in general, a better way is to do:

```
 class A:
     friend = Friend(B)
```

In this case B isn't defined at that point, but you can easily do:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

A.friend = Friend(B)
B.friend = Friend(A)
```